# Cookies in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, cookies, identityserver4

Can someone explain the purpose of the cookies which are sent to the user browser after successful login in Identity Server4. Also I have three smaller related questions at the bottom.

The client is using cookie middleware in ASP.NET Core defined in the **Startup.cs** file.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication()
```

It's quite obvious which tokens Identity Server created and which cookies the ASP.NET Core middleware creates, but I'm not sure what content each cookie containts.

ASP.NET Core middleware decided to create chunked cookies probably due to the cookie size (4050B + 865B).

I have been trying to find a way of decrypting the cookies to read the values using the [Data Protection](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/index.html) API provided by ASP.NET Core without any luck.

- idsvr
- idsvr.session
- .AspNetCore.coookie
- .AspNetCore.coookieC1
- .AspNetCore.coookieC2
- .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.

[image: Screenshot from developer tools in Internet Explorer]

1. Which cookie contains the id_token, access_token issued by Identity Server?
2. CookieName can be used to change the name of the cookie created by ASP.NET Core middleware, should different clients share same cookie name or do they need to have separate session cookies?
3. Can the Identity Server cookies be decrypted by using the [Data Protection](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/index.html) API?

Comment: I realize it has been nearly six years, but were you able to figure out how to decrypt and read the Identity Server cookies?

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK id_token, access_token are not stored in a cookie by default. But you can store them in the session cookie(cookie created by ASP.NET Core middleware) if needed. [Here is how it is done](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid)/Startup.cs) for identity server 3 with hybrid flow using OpenID connect OWIN middleware. There should be a similar option for asp.net core middleware as well.
2. Each client can have same cookie name but they are not required to do so. BY THE WAY, The cookie can only be accessed by the client who created it.
3. I do not know.